# Is it possible to read out the "Album Artist" ID3 tag with spotlight query?

Tags: spotlight, mp3, id3-tag

I know that a spotlight query is capable of reading the "Artist" ID3 tag of mp3 files but is it also possible to read out (speak) the "Artist Album" ID3 field? This [source](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kMDItemAuthors) doesnt say anything about it?

Comment: How are you doing you query.

Comment: Actually I'm doing my query with a third party software called Hazel, but it relies on spotlight.

Comment: Can you show you Hazel rules and actions you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible. You can check to see the metadata associated with a file by using the `mdls` command.

```
mdls ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/Artist/Album/Song.mp3
```

Try it with a song that has an Album Artist and you unfortunately won't see it in the output.